# Jest ReferenceError on globally defined JS constants within Angular components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jest-preset-angular

Today I've started using Jest to UnitTest some of our TypeScript files within our Angular project. After the initial Jest setup was done, creating a test for a pure TypeScript method in our `util.ts` was pretty straight-forward. Now I'm working on testing something in an Angular component, and I'm encountering an error because of our global constants within an imported other Component. So I'm looking for a way to either:

1. Give a default to these global variable in my Jest UnitTest class itself by setting them in a `beforeAll`.
2. Have a (separated) `custom-jest-constants.setup.ts` file to predefine all global variables for all tests

I'll save you the details of the steps I did this morning to setup and configure Jest within Angular, but I ended up with the following relevant changes because of it:

**Within the `angularelements/` root folder:**

Added `jest.config.ts`:

```
export default {
  clearMocks: true,
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
};
```

Added `setup-jest.ts`:

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

Added `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "CommonJs",
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Modified `package.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...,
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.3",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^12.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Within a new test folder:**

Added `util.test.ts` and `question.component.test.ts`, what they do isn't too relevant.

**The error I'm getting when I run `npm test`:**

```
 PASS  test/app/util.test.ts
 FAIL  test/app/questionnaire/runtime/question/question.component.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: maxFileUploadSizeInKb is not defined

      42 |   ...
    > 43 |   private static readonly UPLOAD_LIMIT_IN_BYTES = +maxFileUploadSizeInKb * 1000;
         |                                                    ^
      44 |   private static readonly IMAGE_UPLOAD_LIMIT_IN_BYTES = +maxImageFileUploadSizeInKb * 1000;
      45 |   ...

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/document-panel/document-uploading/document-uploading.component.ts:43:52)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/questionnaire/runtime/questionnaire-document-panel/questionnaire-document-panel.component.ts:10:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/questionnaire/runtime/question/question.component.ts:16:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/app/questionnaire/runtime/question/question.component.test.ts:1:1)
```

As for the relevant code within the `document-uploading.component.ts`:

```
declare const maxFileUploadSizeInKb: string;
declare const maxImageFileUploadSizeInKb: string;

@Component({ ... })
export class DocumentUploadingComponent extends ... {
  private static readonly UPLOAD_LIMIT_IN_BYTES = +maxFileUploadSizeInKb * 1000;
  private static readonly IMAGE_UPLOAD_LIMIT_IN_BYTES = +maxImageFileUploadSizeInKb * 1000;
```

Those declared constants are global constants that we define in our `javascriptPre.jspf`:

```
...
<script ...>
   var maxFileUploadSizeInKb = '<%=Util.parseInt(SettingManager.get(Setting.maximumFileSizeInKb), Setting.DEFAULT_MAX_FILE_SIZE_KB)%>';
   var maxImageFileUploadSizeInKb = '<%=Util.parseInt(SettingManager.get(Setting.maximumImageFileSizeInKb), Setting.DEFAULT_MAX_IMAGE_FILE_SIZE_KB)%>';
</script>
...
```

Which will basically inject the settings we've defined in our Java backend to this globally defined JS variable, which is accessible within our Angular/Typescript classes as can be seen in the `document-uploading.component.ts`.

If I temporarily modify the DocumentUploadingComponent to hard-coded constants like this:

```
private static readonly UPLOAD_LIMIT_IN_BYTES = 5_000_000;
private static readonly IMAGE_UPLOAD_LIMIT_IN_BYTES = 400_000;
```

Everything works as intended when I run `npm test`.

So, back to the original question: how could I overwrite/setup the `maxFileUploadSizeInKb`/`maxImageFileUploadSizeInKb` to some default value, either within a custom Jest setup file or in a `beforeAll` within my UnitTest file (or elsewhere perhaps)?

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted my answer above I finally found the solution, which was simpler than I thought.

In `jest.config.ts` I've added:

```
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/custom-jest-setup.ts'],
```

And in that added new `custom-jest-setup.ts` file within my `angularelements/` folder I've used:

```
// @ts-ignore
global.maxFileUploadSizeInKb = 5000;
// @ts-ignore
global.maxImageFileUploadSizeInKb = 400;
```

And that's it. My UnitTests run without any issues now!